# Reactjs displaying Uncaught Error when trying to display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Am trying to code a reactjs pagination from scratch but am stuck on the way  with the following errors below.

1.) Reactjs displays the following errors when trying to display records from database
 **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"**

2.) When I click on Page link, it says **"Uncaught ReferenceError: displayRecords is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick"**. It seems that either **displayRecords()** functions is not well defined or binded in the javascript below.

3.) When I click on the dropdown link, it says **"Uncaught ReferenceError: changeDisplayRowCount is not defined
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange"**. It seems that either **changeDisplayRowCount()** functions is not well defined or binded in the javascript below.

Please can someone run the script and help me fix the issue. At least even if its just the first error (**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"**).

```
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links"  onclick="displayRecords('10', '1');" >Page</a>
<label> Rows Limit: 
<select name="show" onChange="changeDisplayRowCount(this.value);">
  <option value="10" >10</option>
  <option value="20" >20</option>
  <option value="30" >30</option>
</select>
</label>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum) {
      var show = numRecords;
      var pagenum = pageNum;

      alert(show);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getrecords.php',
        data: {
          show: numRecords,
          pagenum: pageNum
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          show: numRecords;
          pagenum: pagenum;

          $('#display')
            .html(data)
            .show();

          //console.log(email);

          console.log(show);
          console.log(pagenum);

          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(jqXHR) {
          console.log(jqXHR);
        }.bind(this)
      });
    } // end displayRecords

    function changeDisplayRowCount(numRecords) {
      displayRecords(numRecords, 1);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      displayRecords(10, 1);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data ? (
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}} />
        ) : (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


</script>
```

**getrecords.php**

```
<?php

echo $page = $_GET['pagenum'];
echo $show = $_GET["show"];

// pagination
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are referencing a function, `displayRecords` that is not in the global scope of the page, it's defined inside of `componentDidMount`, which is not available to your HTML tag.
2. `select` tags are not valid inside of a `label` tag.
3. You are using both HTML and React, why?
4. You are binding `this` inside an unbound function, where `this` resolved to the root scope, which is why `setState` is not defined.
5. You are setting the inner HTML of a tag using jquery and not react ... why?
6. You are using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, you shouldn't be, there are better ways.
7. You are calling `$(document).ready` from within a React component ... the document is ready if the component has been mounted, this is un-needed logic.

Here is the direct fix for your issue:

```
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="links"  onclick="displayRecords('10', '1');" >Page</a>
<label> Rows Limit: 
<select name="show" onChange="changeDisplayRowCount(this.value);">
  <option value="10" >10</option>
  <option value="20" >20</option>
  <option value="30" >30</option>
</select>
</label>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
window.displayRecords = function(){
    alert('Component not mounted yet.');
};

window.changeDisplayRowCount = function(){
    alert('Component not mounted yet.');
}
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    window.displayRecords = (function displayRecords(numRecords, pageNum) {
      var show = numRecords;
      var pagenum = pageNum;

      alert(show);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'getrecords.php',
        data: {
          show: numRecords,
          pagenum: pageNum
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          show: numRecords;
          pagenum: pagenum;

          $('#display')
            .html(data)
            .show();

          //console.log(email);

          console.log(show);
          console.log(pagenum);

          this.setState({data: data});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(jqXHR) {
          console.log(jqXHR);
        }.bind(this)
      });
    }.bind(this) // end displayRecords

    window.changeDisplayRowCount = function changeDisplayRowCount(numRecords) {
      displayRecords(numRecords, 1);
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      displayRecords(10, 1);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data ? (
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}} />
        ) : (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


</script>
```

While this will fix your issue (or so it probably should), here is what your code *should* look something like:

```
function PageLink({page,onClick}){
  return <div className="pageLink" onClick={onClick.bind(null,page)}>
    {page}
  </div>;
}

function RowSelector({selected,onChange}){
  return (
    <div className="rowSelector">
      <label>Rows Limit:</label>
      <select onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} value={selected}>
          {[10,20,30].map(num => <option key={num} value={num}>{num}</option>)}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

function DataItem({item}){
  // Assumes data is a map with a name key.
  return <div>{item.name}</div>;
}

class Pagination extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPage: 0,
      rowLimit: 10,
      data: [],
      loading: false
    };
    this.setCurrentPage = this.setCurrentPage.bind(this);
    this.setRowLimit = this.setRowLimit.bind(this);
  }

  updateData(){
    this.setState({loading: true});
    // This is just for mock purposes, remove this and use the ajax logic below.
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        data: (function(rowLimit){
          let res = [];
          for(let i = 0; i < rowLimit; i++){
            res.push({name: String(i)});
          }
          return res;
        })(this.state.rowLimit)
      })
    },1000);
    return;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'getrecords.php',
      data: {
        show: this.state.rowLimit,
        pagenum: this.state.currentPage
      },
      cache: false,
      success: data =>  this.setState({data,loading: false}),
      error: jqXHR => {
        this.setState({loading:false});
        console.log(jqXHR);
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps,prevState){
    if(this.state.currentPage != prevState.currentPage || this.state.rowLimit != prevState.rowLimit){
      this.updateData();
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.updateData();
  }

  setCurrentPage(currentPage){
    this.setState({currentPage});
  }

  setRowLimit(rowLimit){
    this.setState({rowLimit})
  }

  renderLoading(){
    return <div>Loading ...</div>;
  }

  renderData(){
    return <div>
      {this.state.data.map(
         (item,key) => <DataItem item={item} key={key}/>
      )}
    </div>
  }

    render(){
        return (
      <div>
        <PageLink page={1} onClick={this.setCurrentPage}/>
        <RowSelector onChange={this.setRowLimit} selected={this.rowLimit}/>
        {this.state.loading ? this.renderLoading() : this.renderData()}
      </div>
    );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Pagination />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

You can see this working here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qPoBjN

Comment: Kyle, you are really wonderful. Your first direct fixed code was awesome. it solve error problem 2 and 3 listed above. but am still having just this error  1 problem. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" within the render propertises . The result should be displayed with reactjs "dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}}"  and not  with   "$('#display').html(data).show();".. Am sorry for the confusion. You can view the error  from the web console. Please this is just the last request. Thanks for your timely effort. Am still counting on you.

Comment: @bowman87 Please see the updated code ... also, I highly recommend you re-write your code to be more like my second example. Currently you are doing some very weird things that make no sense and are against standards. Also, I recommend you read this article: https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Comment: Hello Kyle, its not displaying anything. it still shows error . "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined" within the render propertises .